# laravel database notificaion paginate not working

Tags: php, database, laravel, eloquent, pagination

Hi I try to implement pagination on laravel database notification but it seems not working at all.

**Code:**

```
$notifications = $user->notifications->paginate(3) ;
```

**Error:**

```
BadMethodCallException
Method Illuminate\Notifications\DatabaseNotificationCollection::paginate does not exist.
```

According to here
https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/15315
and here
https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/eloquent/how-to-paginate-laravel-53-database-notifications `$user->notifications->paginate(3);` this is the correct way to paginate.

Does laravel version update cause this not working ??

```
public function newCollection(array $models = [])
{
    return new DatabaseNotificationCollection($models);
}
```

Its returning a new collection in side the `DatabaseNotification` class.
Any turnaround method? Or my code is wrong?

Thanks for reading any help will be highly appreciated (bow).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding

```
$user->notifications()->paginate(3);
```

instead of

```
$user->notifications
```

Comment: well i think you are right how careless i am thanks bro

Comment: How to get read and unread notifications separately including pagination?